# Why does C++ see this as ambiguous function reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ambiguity, std

Why might my compiler see the following GetLength function pointer as ambiguous
pseudo-code:

```
size_t GetLength(char*);
size_t GetLength(wchar_t*);
struct ITEM { };
double GetLength(ITEM*);

CString GetInfo(ITEM * item, std::function<double (ITEM*)> fn)
{
  ... omitted for clarity
}

ITEM * item = new ITEM;
cout << GetInfo(item, GetLength);  // <- ambiguous error
```

GetInfo only allows something of the double return + ITEM* argument pattern.  So why is it considering (and not discarding) the two string based variations of GetLength?

Comment: Maybe because of the syntax error?

Comment: `function<double (ITEM*>` is `(` a typo or am I missing a syntactic part of C++?

Comment: Sorry for the type-o!  I was trying to reduce the scenario to essentials.  :)

Comment: In clang I get `no overload of 'GetLength' matching 'std::function<double (ITEM *)>' for 2nd argument`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The constructor for `std::function<...>` is *templated* because it has to be able to support any function-like input type. There's no single type to try to deduce to, so your overloads are all possible to construct with; it wouldn't be until later into compilation later that an error arose for a type mismatch.

You could do this:

```
GetInfo(item, static_cast<double(*)(ITEM*)>(GetLength));
```

To explicitly discard the other overloads.

---

In other words, it's the same reason this won't work:

```
void foo(int);
void foo(void*);

struct bar
{
    template <typename T>
    bar(T f)
    {
        f(5);
    }
};

bar b(foo);
```

Even though the constructor body for `bar` will only work with `void foo(int)`,
it wants to support any function where `f(5)` will work so the argument type is templated. This allows any function to work in that place, which means the compiler cannot deduce a single best overload to use.

---

I think that one language-level solution is for an overload set to actually be a functor itself. That is, given:

```
void foo(int);
void foo(void*);

template <typename T>
double foo(int, T);
```

Naming `foo` (as in `bar(foo)` or even just `foo(5)`) results in an instance of this type:

```
struct __foo_overload_set // internal
{
    // forwarders
    void operator()(int __arg0) const
    {
        // where __foo0 is the zeroth overload, etc...
        return __foo0(__arg0);
    }

    void operator()(void* __arg0) const
    {
        return __foo1(__arg0);
    }

    template <typename __Arg1>
    double operator()(int __arg0, __Arg1&& __arg1) const
    {
        return __foo2(__arg0, std::forward<__Arg1>(__arg1));
    }

    // converters
    typedef void(*__foo0_type)(int);

    operator __foo0_type() const
    {
        return __foo0;
    }

    typedef void(*__foo1_type)(void*);

    operator __foo1_type() const
    {
        return __foo1;
    }

    template <typename T>
    struct __foo2_type
    {
        typedef void(*type)(int, T);
    };

    template <typename T>
    operator typename __foo2_type<T>::type() const
    {
        return __foo2;
    }
};
```

Which, being callable itself, *will* compile in the context we want. (AFAIK, it does not introduce any ambiguities that don't already exist, though it's completely untested.)

Comment: Hm, the details are interesting, though. You cannot convert `wchar_t*` to `ITEM*`, so wouldn't the templated constructor check for free functions with *convertible* argument types?

Comment: I guess it's intuitive to me that a std::function that explicitly specifies the argument and return types would have to apply such restrictions sooner, and counter-intuitive that this is left until later.  Bummer.

Comment: @KerrekSB: AFAIK it's not possible in general. You can't perform any `enable_if`'s, for example, because that would only happen *after* `T` is deduced. The best you could do is add constructor overloads for an exact free function match, but that leaves all the other function-like value ambiguous.

Comment: @GMan: Thanks! It can get a bit hairy at times to think about the order in which arguments are deduced :-)

Comment: I know its kind of long shot, but there might be something in boost that enables a function only if it supports call operator with specified signature (to be used with enable_if)

Comment: @GMan the cast is slightly off - should be: GetInfo(item, static_cast<double(\*)(ITEM\*)>(GetLength));

Comment: @Dani: See my comment to Kerrek: there's no `T` with which to test.

Comment: @GMan: There is, because `std::function` has a template parameter for the class and a template parameter for the constructor, which is two to compair.

Comment: @GMan so if I'd used a function-pointer definition, then it wouldn't have been ambiguous, but it would have eliminated non-function-ptrs such as functors and lambdas?

Comment: @Dani: "and a template parameter for the constructor" No it doesn't, that's the problem. Where did it deduce a single `T` from, with an overloaded set of functions? There are multiple types there. You can't deduce `T` until *after* you select a single overload.

Comment: I've added my own solution idea, for those wondering how this problem might be solved.

Comment: @GMan: It can try every one and reject ones that fail, just like SFINAE does

Comment: @Dani: You're hand-waving. I'm not sure how else to explain this without going in circles. To use `enable_if`, we need a single type. To get a single type from a set of candidate functions, you have to eliminate all of them but one. Because there are no restrictions on `T` (it can be deduced to be anything), no single best candidate function exists, so a single type for `T` is not deduced, and an error results. At no point do we have a single `T`, so at no point does `enable_if` ever come into play. Let me repeat that: you need a `T` **first**, then `enable_if` can be applied.

Comment: @GMan: No, what I mean is the compiler will try each overload with the function and see what fits. then for each overload there is only one `T` to try with `enable_if`

Comment: @Dani: No, actually, it won't; do you have any justification for your claim at all? That's just simply wrong, that's not how template deduction works. Try it yourself and stop hand-waving.

Answer (score 0):

Your braces dont match. That's why the compiler cant understand you

```
CString GetInfo(ITEM * item, std::function<double ITEM*> fn)
```

Comment: Although this is also the first thing I've seen, I'm not sure it's not a copying error, I think the problem is indeed with ambiguity (though I'm not sure why).

Comment: Sorry about the sloppy typing!  But that's a red-herring :)

Comment: :-) - GMans answer is better anyway - I didnt look past the typo